# How to get property name in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have this in firebase.

```
{
 'users': 
   {
    'random1': 
      {
       'name': 'David'
      }
   },{
    'random2':
     {
      'name': 'Dan'
     }  
   }
}
```

How to list out `random1` and `random2` using angularFire.
What I want to do is to get random1 and random2 then pass it url for later remove.

Example

```
ref.child('users/' + therandomidhere);
$scope.remove = userRef.remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you can remove a property in an object by simply setting it to null. For example:

```js
function MyController($scope, angularFire) {
  angularFire(ref, $scope, "users", {}).then(function() {
    // You can delete random1 by doing:
    $scope.users["random1"] = null;
    // Or:
    delete $scope.users["random1"];
    // You can enumerate all the keys by:
    for (var key in $scope.users) {
      console.log(key);
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your methods but not work. I added a plunker. Please check it. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/iOxxrPeil4MrKnVnGE37?p=preview

Comment: You're trying to delete from an array with splice, but it's an object. Fixed Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/b1LXs4xtKasHByuhDNBk?